# Spring MVC - Adding confirmation message to same page - maybe additional model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to display a successful message on a database update for the application that I am developing.

I have a model that contains the contents of the domain object that is being posted to the database. I don't want to add a property to the current model object. Is there a way to pass an additional model object to send a confirmation which I can then access to the JSP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, make all your controllers extend a `BaseController`. Have a method in `BaseController` name `displayMessage(String displayString)`. Call this method with appropriate message from your Controllers when you want to display a message on your jsp. What this method will do is add a string object to your model object. In your jsp page check if this string object is `null`, if not go ahead and print it out. Further additions to the `displayMessage` can be the type of message (INFO, ERROR, etc)